# Regex wheel size or digits after point

Tags: regex

These are 2 samples:

```
Size: 15x6.5
Size: 15x7
```

I need a regex command to capture the digits before "x" and another regex command to capture digits after.

I want to obtain something like this:

```
Size: 15x6.5 --> 1) 15 2) 6.5
Size: 15x7   --> 1) 15 2) 7
```

Comment: Which regular expression engine / language do you use?

Comment: surely `[0-9.]*` would do the job?

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expression: `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

You didn't specified the regular expression engine you are using.

### Python

```
>>> import re
>>> matched = re.search(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', 'Size: 15x6.5')
>>> matched.groups()
('15', '6.5')
>>> matched = re.search(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', 'Size: 15x7')
>>> matched.groups()
('15', '7')
```

### Ruby

```
>> 'Size: 15x6.5'.scan(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)
=> [["15", "6.5"]]
>> 'Size: 15x7'.scan(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)
=> [["15", "7"]]
```

### Javascript

```
> 'Size: 15x6.5'.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)
["15x6.5", "15", "6.5"]
> 'Size: 15x7'.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)
["15x7", "15", "7"]
```

**UPDATE**

Use `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=x)` and `(?<=x)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Comment: I am sorry I am  using JavaScript engine. I put firs script to check, but it didn't get right result http://gyazo.com/81025629d01e1e488a201d3b23b03a8c, it highlighted only first digits and only first size . I need expression for any digits before "x" and any digits with "."  after "x". It should be 2   different expressions

Comment: Hm, it's not working at all, I found regex for fist digits before "x"
[x\d\s1-91-9][x\d\s1-91-9][x\d\s1-91-9], now I need expression after "x".

Comment: I am using just plain Regex, in editor. http://gyazo.com/f23b098f8cd241e2ca771ea99c70ee58

Comment: Now it's work! Thanks!
Can you please also do same thing for this 
"Valencia 7x17/5x112 D70.1 ET48 Silver" There should be 7 expressions: 
1)"Valencia" 2) "7" 3)"17" 4) "5x112" 5) 70.1 6)48 7) Silver.